# clang: initialising a lock reference from a mutex

Tags: c++, g++, clang

This program is compiled by clang:

```
#include <mutex>

int main() {
    std::mutex mtx;
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex>& lock(mtx);
    return 0;
}
```

Other major compilers refuse it (I have tried gcc, msvc, and icc). This is an error message from gcc:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const 
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex>&’ from expression of type ‘std::mutex’
```

Others give similar errors.

Is clang right or wrong? Can this be reproduced with a simpler example not involving library classes? I have tried but to no avail.

**Edit** this seems to be the minimal reproduction:

```
struct A {};

struct X
{
    explicit X(A&) {};
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    const X& x(a);
}
```

Interestingly, an `int` in place of `A` does trigger the error message in clang (which is why I could not reproduce this initially).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the relevant chapter and verse of the C++ standard; I can only refer to [CppReference on Converting Constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) right now (emphasis mine):

> A constructor that is **not** declared with the specifier explicit and which can be called with a single parameter (until C++11) is called a **converting constructor**.
>
> **Unlike** explicit constructors, which are **only considered during direct initialization** (which includes explicit conversions such as static_cast), converting constructors are also considered during copy initialization, as part of user-defined conversion sequence.

So:

```
struct A {};

struct X
{
    explicit X(A const &) {};
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    const X& x1(A());                 // OK, direct init (no A object after init)
    const X& x3(a);                   // NOK, copy init
}
```

Comment: @n.m.: I am not qualified to make *that* particular call. The above is merely how I would explain the error message for myself; I'll leave the judgement to higher authorities... ;-)